# PHP CODEIGNITER UPDATE issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

I can't update data in a record in CodeIgniter .

I have posted the code below:-

**//CONTROLLER
//RESERVATION.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reservation extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('reservation_model','reservation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('manage_reservation');
    }
    public function reservationview()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('view_reservation');
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->reservation->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $reservation) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $reservation->id;
            $row[] = $reservation->dateReserved;
            $row[] = $reservation->requestedBy;
            $row[] = $reservation->facility;
            $row[] = $reservation->dateFrom;
            $row[] = $reservation->dateTo;
            $row[] = $reservation->timeStart;
            $row[] = $reservation->timeEnd;
            $row[] = $reservation->status;
            $row[] = $reservation->items;
            $row[] = $reservation->purpose;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_reservation('."'".$reservation->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_reservation('."'".$reservation->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->reservation->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->reservation->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    public function ajax_edit($id)
    {

        $data = $this->reservation->get_by_id($id);

        $data->dateFrom = ($data->dateFrom == '0000-00-00') ? '' : $data->dateFrom;
        $data->dateTo = ($data->dateTo == '0000-00-00') ? '' : $data->dateTo;       // if 0000-00-00 set tu empty for datepicker compatibility
        echo json_encode($data);

    }

    public function ajax_add()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                'dateReserved' => $this->input->post('dateReserved'),
                'requestedBy' => $this->input->post('requestedBy'),
                'facility' => $this->input->post('facility'),
                'dateFrom' => $this->input->post('dateFrom'),
                'dateTo' => $this->input->post('dateTo'),
                'timeStart' => $this->input->post('timeStart'),
                'timeEnd' => $this->input->post('timeEnd'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'items' => $this->input->post('items'),
                'purpose' => $this->input->post('purpose'),

            );
        $insert = $this->reservation->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_update()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(

                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                'dateReserved' => $this->input->post('dateReserved'),
                'requestedBy' => $this->input->post('requestedBy'),
                'facility' => $this->input->post('facility'),
                'dateFrom' => $this->input->post('dateFrom'),
                'dateTo' => $this->input->post('dateTo'),
                'timeStart' => $this->input->post('timeStart'),
                'timeEnd' => $this->input->post('timeEnd'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'items' => $this->input->post('items'),
                'purpose' => $this->input->post('purpose'),



            );
        $this->reservation->update(array('id' => $this->input->post('id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_delete($id)
    {
        $this->reservation->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }


    private function _validate()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['error_string'] = array();
        $data['inputerror'] = array();
        $data['status'] = TRUE;

        if($this->input->post('requestedBy') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'requestedBy';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Requested Name is required*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('dateFrom') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'dateFrom';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please Select a Date*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('dateTo') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'dateTo';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please Select a Date*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('timeStart') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'timeStart';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please select a Time*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('timeEnd') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'timeEnd';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please select a Time*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('status') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'status';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please Indicate Status*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('items') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'items';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please select an Item*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('purpose') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'purpose';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Please indicate a Purpose*';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($data['status'] === FALSE)
        {
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

**//MODEL
//Reservation_model.php**

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Reservation_model extends CI_Model {

        var $table = 'tblreservation';
        var $column_order = array('id','dateReserved','requestedBy','facility','dateFrom','dateTo','timeStart','timeEnd','status','items','purpose',null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
        var $column_search = array('id','dateReserved','requestedBy','facility','dateFrom','dateTo','timeStart','timeEnd','status','items','purpose'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable

        var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

        private function _get_datatables_query()
        {

            $this->db->from($this->table);

            $i = 0;

            foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
            {
                if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
                {

                    if($i===0) // first loop
                    {
                        $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                        $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }

                    if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                        $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
                }
                $i++;
            }

            if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
            {
                $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
            } 
            else if(isset($this->order))
            {
                $order = $this->order;
                $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
            }
        }

        function get_datatables()
        {
            $this->_get_datatables_query();
            if($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }

        function count_filtered()
        {
            $this->_get_datatables_query();
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->num_rows();
        }

        public function count_all()
        {
            $this->db->from($this->table);
            return $this->db->count_all_results();
        }

        public function get_by_id($id)
        {
            $this->db->from($this->table);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->row();
        }

        public function save($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        public function update($where, $data)
        {
            $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
            return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }

        public function delete_by_id($id)
        {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->delete($this->table);
        }


}
```

**VIEW =  manage_reservation.php = save function**

```
function save()
{
    $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
    var url;

    if(save_method == 'add') {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('reservation/ajax_add')?>";
    } else {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('reservation/ajax_update')?>";
    }

    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                {
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                }
            }
            $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
            $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

        }
    });
}
```

**NEWBIE TO CODE IGNITER any help will be appreciated :)**

Comment: what's error message ?

Comment: i can CREATE READ DELETE but i couldnt update any data no errors popping out its just i doesnt update

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. You can use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to emphasize text.

Comment: Tip: Instead of loading url helper multiple times put it in __construct area or load it in autoload it in config/autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
public function update($where, $data){
   $this->db->where($where);
   $this->db->set($data); //array of new data
   $this->db->update($this->table);
   return $this->db->affected_rows();
 }
```

Comment: wait, did u update data via ajax? try to test ajax_update() via postman to see if there is any error

Comment: YES via ajax :(

Comment: test your ajax post url via postman to see any error message https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45grlRBdEl3N0ZLQ0M4TmNxUjg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: if there is any error, maybe the problem is with your ajax request, make sure your form and input value is ok,

Comment: here is my project file im so noob in codeigniter please help me :(

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxRXyksPy1PHS3E4ZUh5azBtRUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the problem is with your modal dialog

<input name="id" placeholder="Auto Generated" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="true" disabled="disabled">

change disabled="disabled" to readonly="readonly"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45grlRBdEl3SDFvUXI0VHJYQ2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: working now man thanks man for your help ! its my first time using codeigniter so im a bit stupid to it cheeers!

Comment: By the way man can you assist me on login logout sessions? You know i just know basic crud of codeigniter if its ok with you? :( i make a thread and they doesnt helping

Comment: you can check on their docs https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html ask if you got any problem

Answer (score 0):

Please print your query after the update statement, this will help you to know whether you query is correct or not.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: here is my project file im so noob in codeigniter please help me :(

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxRXyksPy1PHS3E4ZUh5azBtRUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry mate, try to debug yourself. All you have to do is print the update query in your model file.

    public function update($where, $data){$this->db->where($where);
           $this->db->set($data); //array of new data
           $this->db->update($this->table);
           echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please check that query in model

**Controller :**

```
$update_id = array();
$update_id['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
 $data = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                'dateReserved' => $this->input->post('dateReserved'),
                'requestedBy' => $this->input->post('requestedBy'),
                'facility' => $this->input->post('facility'),
                'dateFrom' => $this->input->post('dateFrom'),
                'dateTo' => $this->input->post('dateTo'),
                'timeStart' => $this->input->post('timeStart'),
                'timeEnd' => $this->input->post('timeEnd'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'items' => $this->input->post('items'),
                'purpose' => $this->input->post('purpose'),
            );

$result = $this->reservation->update('table_name',$update_id, $data);
```

**Model :**

```
 $this->db->where($where);
 $this->db->update($table, $data);
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```